# php stristr() not working properly

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have collected this code from w3school and changed the code a little.But now stristr() is not working as per my wish.For example,when i type "E",the result is showing "Eva" for 5 times and when i type "Ev" it is showing "Eva" for 3 times.Point to be noted that,the array has 5 words start with "E" and 3 words start with "Ev".And another problem is,how can i save username as elements of an array in a JSON file and loop through the data(username) for a search hint.That means i don't want to use hard coded data like this rather i want to use dynamic data for search prediction.

```
<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Diana";
$a[] = "Eva";
$a[] = "Fiona";
$a[] = "Gunda";
$a[] = "Hege";
$a[] = "Inga";
$a[] = "Johanna";
$a[] = "Kitty";
$a[] = "Linda";
$a[] = "Nina";
$a[] = "Ophelia";
$a[] = "Petunia";
$a[] = "Amanda";
$a[] = "Raquel";
$a[] = "Cindy";
$a[] = "Doris";
$a[] = "Eve";
$a[] = "Evita";
$a[] = "Sunniva";
$a[] = "Tove";
$a[] = "Unni";
$a[] = "Violet";
$a[] = "Liza";
$a[] = "Elizabeth";
$a[] = "Ellen";
$a[] = "Wenche";
$a[] = "Vicky";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr( substr($name, 0, $len),$q)) {
            if ($hint === "") {
               $Name= stristr( substr($name,0),$q);
                $hint =$Name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $Name";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

Comment: Check your error log, that code produces a stream of errors

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** it should be `$hint .= ", $name";`

you can alter your loop so you put found results in an array:

```
<?php
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    $found = array();
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr( substr($name, 0, $len),$q)) {
            array_push($found, $name);
        }
    }

    print_r($found);
}
?>
```